# Organizing user images

Tags: php, directory-structure

I am developing a social system where users can upload images.

I am not very sure how I should structure my files. The two ideas I have is the following:

1. Add a folder with the userID as name and put all the users images in there
2. Have a single folder for all images, and give each image a unique name

Which one of the two would be better? Is it the proper way to organize images?

Comment: I would combine the two. Folder per user and unique names per image.

Comment: This depends on what your requirements are, in theory if you want to be able to remove users easily a different folder may be better, but there are pros/cons for both. Can you provide more context?

Comment: It's a dating site where, obviously, the pictures of a user is very essential for the sites purpose. Most users are going to have multiple pictures. A gallery will be attached to each profile

Comment: I don't recommend putting all images in a single directory. Reading the directory will be slow and on some systems the number of files in one directory is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

When you use have a gallery with images stored in a directory per user, you also have to worry about duplicates (say user will upload several files with the same name).

On the other hand in the first case you might run into performance issues related to number of files in a single directory (if you have more than 10k of files it might lag).

Solution I like is is to create a unique name and crop it into several parts to create a directory structure.

For example:

1. Generate from a file `image.jpg` (look into [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)) a unique name, say
    `nfsr53a5gb`
2. Add to it the original extension so it becomes `nfsr53a5gb.jpg`
3. Split it with `/` into `nf/sr/53/a5/gb.jpg`
4. [Create missing folders](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) as you go (see `recursive` parameter)

You won't hit the penalty for number of files in a directory soon and you won't get a collision and files have URLs difficult to guess.

A nice touch is to add a controller for getting those files which will change the name to the original name (store it in database and switch headers). Use it only for a dedicated download button as this might be too CPU and I/O intensive for many images embedded on a page.

In order to do this you have to modify headers like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=YOUR_FILE_NAME.YOUR_EXTENSION
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for #2 option, OR if number of user increases number folders will keep on increse.

For fetching images in your code also this method will be simpler.

Comment: *Why* would option number 2 be the better one?

Comment: It reduces the complexity in your code, And it consumes less server space than #1. Ref some php frame work you can see #2 is followed everywhere.

Comment: to lookup in a directory with large number of files also slows it down, so there's a tradeoff.